# What type of statistical analysis to perform?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, mixed-model, linear-model

I have an experiment with 10 subjects.

Each of them has to exert force and real-time feedback is received. Each subject experiences all 3 types of feedback (within-subject factor).

Moreover, each type of feedback may be filtered either at 2 or 5 Hz. Again, each subject experiences both filtering frequencies (within-subject factor).

Finally, for each feedback type and filtering frequency, the participant must follow a trace with one of two mean force levels. Once more, both mean force levels are presented to every subject for every feedback type and frequency combination (within-subject factor).

Should I implement a 3-way ANOVA or a Linear Mixel Model (e.g. outcome ~ feedback * frequency * force + (1|subject))? Or something else?

Comment: Do the subjects all receive the same combinations of feedback, frequency and force, and each subject only once for each combination?

Comment: @RobertLong Do the subjects all receive the same combinations of fedback, frequency and force? -> Yes. All of them (3 feedbacks * 2 frequencies * 2 forces = 12 combinations for each subject). BUT each subject receives 2 times each combinations, so there are in total 24 trials per subject.

Comment: OK, and are you interested in any change between measurement occasions ?

Comment: @RobertLong No. Different trials are just meant as a mean to increase statistical power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the measurements are repeated for each subject, there is likely to be correlation within subjects because the measurements are not independent. A mixed effect model with random intercepts for subjects is a good way to model these data, whereas a 3-way ANOVA would lead to biased results.

Comment: The model you described would be coded as error ~ feedback * frequency * force + (1|subject)? I say this because of the doubt about the variables being nested

Comment: If `error` is your outcome variable then yes. These are no nested random effects since you have only 1 grouping variable, but you have *clustered* data because of the repeated measures.

Comment: I fitted the LME model as recommended by you. When checking for model soundness, I found the residuals to be really large and also their variance depends linearly on the x values. Because `error` is the outcome variable and is a RMSE, it follows a Chi-squared distribution. Is that affecting my residuals? Thanks for any help

Comment: That's a completely different question to do with model fit, so please describe the experimental setup explaining how all the variables including the response arise, in a new question.

Comment: I posted a new question treating the topic [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/440116/model-selection-for-mixed-effects-regression-correcting-heteroscedasticity)